# To create a chromecast app, do we need or buy something?

Tags: android, chromecast

I created a game for android, and I liked to transmit the game to a smart tv. I already searched about chromecast and they lead me to this:

https://cast.google.com/publish/#/signup

Do i need to buy or need something to program it? 
Sorry for the bad english.
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The documentation appears to be clear: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterApp - to get access to the Google Cast SDK Developer Console there is a separate fee.

Comment: But I need to register to program with chromecast?

Comment: Yes. If you want to actually test with a Chromecast device you'll need to register to add it to your developer list: `c. Register your Google Cast device at the Google Cast SDK Developer Console. You must register the device so that you can use it for testing.` While you may be able to compile an app for Chromecast without the Cast Developer Console. I don't know of any way to test without a physical Chromecast device.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should signup for chromecast developer console.
To be able to test your application in pair with chromecast - you should pair your test device with developer console. for this purposes you need to add serial number of your device to chromecast developer console. @Morrison Chang gave you really helpfull link. developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterApp